# error no-unused-expression: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I am getting an error as:

> error no-unused-expression: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

at else statement in below code. And also showing error as:

> missing semicolon

at same else statement. Below is the error image:

[image]

```
public async setPreselected() :Promise<string>{ 

  let returnedValue : any = Constants.isPreSelectedRolePresent;

 try {

      const folderServerURL = this.state.listUrl + Constants.listsString + Constants.preferencesList;

      let userRole= await UserPreferenceService.updateUserFolder(userTemp,"",folderServerURL,"");

      if(userRole == Constants.prefNull)
      {
        this.setState({preSelected : "All"});

        returnedValue =  Constants.isAll;

        console.log("Previous preference is null, so setting role as ALL" + returnedValue);

        return returnedValue;

      }
      else ( userRole !== null )
      {

        this.setState({preSelected:userRole });

        return returnedValue;
      }
 }
 catch(err)
 {
     console.log(err);
 }
}
```

What is the error I did not get in else statement. I gave spaces to just to check but still face the same error.

Please help ASAP.

Comment: Which one is line no. 309 in your code? Also `setPreselected()` method expects to return `Promise<string>`. check this.

Answer (score 0):

@Swetha Paritala,

Should it be `else if(userRole !== null){...}`in below code?

```
... 
  }
      else ( userRole !== null )
      {

        this.setState({preSelected:userRole });

        return returnedValue;
      }      
...
```

BR